# What's the best way to sanitize destroy_all - Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following controller in `Rails`:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
    def delete_foo(bar):
        Foo.destroy_all("foo = '#{@bar}'")
```

Is

```
Foo.destroy_all("foo = ?", @bar)
```

always valid?

Answer (score 3):

destroy_all works on a relation. Why not do

```
 Foo.where(foo: bar).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 1):

`Foo.destroy_all("foo = ?", @bar)`, This is invalid.

From [apidoc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all), we will find:

```
destroy_all(conditions = nil) public
```

`destroy_all` method only accepts a single argument, the argument can be a string, array, or hash. You cannot pass two arguments.

So you can write like this:

```
Foo.destroy_all("foo = #{@bar}")
Foo.destroy_all(foo: @bar)
Foo.where(foo: @bar).destroy_all
```

Comment: You can be subject for `SQL` attacks there.

Comment: yes, we should think about the security consequences when using an external string in SQL.